# Google Apps Scripts - How to get key value of document from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the key values of the documents in my Firestore database, but I'm not getting it.

This value below:
[image]

This my code:

```
function objectsToArray(objects) {

  var outputArray = [];
  for (var i in objects){
    outputArray.push([

      objects[i].fields.id, objects[i].fields.data, objects[i].fields.acao, 
      objects[i].fields.categoria, objects[i].fields.movimentos, objects[i].fields.descricao

    ]); 

 }
 return outputArray;
}
```

My output Logger.log of JSON:

```
 [20-01-11 19:42:06:370 CET] [{"name":"projects/orcamento- b37bb/databases/(default)/documents/orcamento/0MwgqEm9abho3bpB5yCc","fields": 
 {"categoria":"SUPERMERCADO","data":"2019-07- 31T00:00:00.000Z","descricao":"","acao":"Despesa","movimentos":23.82,"id":107}, 
 "createTime":"2019-12-31T14:35:47.959299Z","updateTime":"2019-12- 31T14:35:47.959299Z"},
```

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does `objects` have a value assigned to it, and what is it?  You can use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(objects))` to print the value to the log, and then view the log.  We need to know the structure of `objects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original data seems to be structured like this:

```
 [
 {
   "name":"projects/orcamento- b37bb/databases/(default)/documents/orcamento/0MwgqEm9abho3bpB5yCc",
   "fields": {
     "categoria":"SUPERMERCADO",
     "data":"2019-07- 31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "descricao":"",
     "acao":"Despesa",
     "movimentos":23.82,
     "id":107
   }, 
   "createTime":"2019-12-31T14:35:47.959299Z",
   "updateTime":"2019-12- 31T14:35:47.959299Z"
 },
```

You want the value: `0MwgqEm9abho3bpB5yCc`

Which is in the element with the `name` property key.

```
function objectsToArray(objects) {
  var L,nameValue,finalValue;

  objects = [
     {
       "name":"projects/orcamento- b37bb/databases/(default)/documents/orcamento/0MwgqEm9abho3bpB5yCc",
       "fields": {
         "categoria":"SUPERMERCADO",
         "data":"2019-07- 31T00:00:00.000Z",
         "descricao":"",
         "acao":"Despesa",
         "movimentos":23.82,
         "id":107
       }, 
       "createTime":"2019-12-31T14:35:47.959299Z",
       "updateTime":"2019-12- 31T14:35:47.959299Z"
     },
    ]

  var outputArray = [];

  L = objects.length;

  for (var i=0;i<L;i++){

    nameValue = objects[i].name;
    Logger.log('nameValue: ' + nameValue)

    finalValue = nameValue.slice(nameValue.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    Logger.log('finalValue: ' + finalValue)

    outputArray.push(finalValue); 

 }

 Logger.log('outputArray: ' + JSON.stringify(outputArray))
 return outputArray;
}
```